# Deleting SQL Database Rows in vb

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, vbscript

I have problem with deleting SQL database rows for next deleting.
For 1st time, it's working normally but 2nd times, i get the error msg (Command parameter[1] is invalid).

I use datagridview for selecting rows(single/multiple), that i want to deleting.
This my codes:

```
    Dim response As MsgBoxResult
    Dim i As Integer
    i = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index

    If Not Trim(DataGridView1.Item("Group", i).Value.ToString) = "Admin" Then
        response = MsgBox("Do you want remove this account ?" & vbNewLine & "Account : " & Trim(DataGridView1.Item("Name", i).Value.ToString), _
                          MsgBoxStyle.Question + MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Delete Data")
        If response = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            If Not MyConnection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                MyConnection.Open()
            End If
            cmd.Connection = MyConnection
            cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM t_User WHERE ID =?"
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@row", 0)
           For Each UserRow As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.SelectedRows
            If Not MyConnection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                    MyConnection.Open()
            End If
                cmd.Connection = MyConnection
                cmd.Parameters("@row").Value = UserRow.Cells("ID").Value
                DataGridView1.Rows.Remove(UserRow)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                DeleteColumns()
                CreateColumns()
                MyConnection.Close()
           Next UserRow
            Me.BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
        End If
    End If
```

Please help me, Your help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Don't close the connection in the for loop. move this line:

```
 MyConnection.Close()
```

after the Next UserRow line.

Or if you do need to reopen the connection after every row [that's uncommon] then you need to redo the full cmd like

```
            cmd.Connection = MyConnection
            cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM t_User WHERE ID =?"
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@row", 0)
```

Comment: I've tried to put in there , but the problem is the same when i'm trying to deleting row by row/multiple rows

Comment: try not to re set the connection, remove:  cmd.Connection = MyConnection

Comment: Still same problem, when i removing that line (cmd.Connection = MyConnection)

Comment: did you checked with the debugger if id has a correct value?